# In the Harry Potter universe, Are metamorphs immortal?

Tags: harry-potter

Is Tonks potentially immortal? If she lived to age 100 and than transformed into her 20 year old version would it stick? Or is it cosmetic only?

Comment: Given that Voldemort never showed the slightest interest in them, almost certainly not. I'd guess that Metamorphagus abilities degrade with age, same as everything else.

Comment: Well since metamorphmagus is an inherent ability and not something anyone can learn, it is possible he looked into them at some point and dismissed it. Ooooh another interesting question is that if someone polyjuiced into Tonks could they use her metamorph abilities? Is it magic or bloodline? If they could(and stayed under polyjuice long enough to learn how) could they morph into Tonks shape permanently, without needing polyjuice anymore?

Comment: metamorphy seems to be a inborn type of self transfiguration one can perform at will.  This question is, therefore, simular to asking if a person can transfigure themselves into a younger person.  Why that isn't possible probably answers this.

Comment: @Tdmut It's possible, but I doubt he'd accept that you couldn't learn/imitate/recreate/steal those abilities (as kaine says, it appears to be self transfiguration. If you could simply transfigure yourself younger he'd be a large step closer to immortality. Though I guess he's more focussed on total immortality...)

Comment: @DavidS wanded transfiguration isnt permanent. So i guess the question is, is metamorphing permanent?

Comment: @Tdmut: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100612/4918 What would happen if you used the hair of a metamorphmagus in Polyjuice potion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Short answer for this is no. Metamorphmagus changes are cosmetic changes. Although it is never explicitly stated.

**A Metamorphmagus is a witch or wizard with the ability to change his or her physical appearance at will.**

> “I’m a Metamorphmagus,” she said, looking back at her reflection and turning her head so that she could see her hair from all directions. “It means I can change my appearance at will,” she added, spotting Harry’s puzzled expression in the mirror behind her. “I was born one. I got top marks in Concealment and Disguise during Auror training without any study at all, it was great.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 3, The Advance Guard*</sup></sub>

It is strongly hinted that Metamorphmagus is similar to taking Polyjuice Potion.

> “Can you learn how to be a Metamorphmagus?” Harry asked her, straightening up, completely forgetting about packing.
>
> “Well, you’ll have to learn the hard way, I’m afraid,” said Tonks. “Metamorphmagi are really rare, they’re born, not made. Most wizards need to use a wand, or potions, to change their appearance. But we’ve got to get going, Harry, we’re supposed to be packing,” she added guiltily, looking around at all the mess on the floor.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 3, The Advance Guard*</sup></sub>

**It only changes the physical appearance, so if you are really old and change your appearance to somebody younger. You will look younger but still feel old.**

Comment: I'm not sure this is 100% correct. When Sirius transforms into a dog, he isn't just a dog in appearance. He has sharp teeth, the bite of a dog, he can run fast like a dog, much faster than a human. This means his muscles are now dog muscles, his tendons, ligaments, etc. are now dog tissue not human. His sense of smell is heightened. It's not simply cosmetic, it's physiological, right?

Comment: @JMFB Sirius is an Animagus (learned trait) while Tonks is a Metamorphmagus (born trait). Different trait, different rules. Though my assumption would be that his dog form aged along with him, so a 40-year old Sirius would have a 40-year old equivalent dog form. Evidence: Scabbers is old as hell and McGonnagal's Cat-form is also an elderly-looking cat.

Comment: @JaredTritsch So when Tonks transforms into a dog, does she run like a dog, is as fast as a dog, have the jaw strength of a dog, etc.?

Comment: @JMFB: when does Tonks transform into a dog? I didn't think she could do that.

Comment: @JMFB please refer this link on limits to metamorphmagus http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/29012/what-are-the-limits-on-a-metamorphmagus

Comment: @Vishvesh I read the three answers, which had three different opinions and I'm still confused. The one who said she could do a pigs nose, so why not a tusks, or hoofs, makes perfect sense. The answer that quoted the wikipedia article said with enough practice she could transform into pretty much everything. One answer said all she could do was change her hair. One answer said she transformed herself into a completely different woman. So which answer are you subscribing to?

Comment: @sumelic my question was hypothetical. Read my comment above.